# Looking for KQL or Powershell or AZ Cli command

Tags: azure, azure-storage, kql, azure-resource-graph

How to get a list Azure storage accounts with sas authentication enabled from all my subscription using
AZ-CLI / Rsource Graph KQL / PowerShell  scipts?

```
az account list --query "[].{ResourceGroupName:resourceGroup,Name:name,SASDisabled:enableAzureStorageTransferAnalysis}" --out table | where SASDisabled==false
```

Answer (score 0):

> list Azure storage accounts with sas authentication enabled

Its not possible to get the data about storage accounts where SAS is Enabled. But if you want to get to know if SAS is used in a particular storage account or not, you can use below KQL Query in logs section of Storage Account and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/shared-key-authorization-prevent?tabs=portal#query-logs-for-requests-made-with-shared-key-or-sas).

```
StorageBlobLogs 
| where AuthenticationType contains "SAS"
```

[image]

Because i have got the logs of usage SAS, then you can get to know that in this storage account SAS is used.